# oauth authentication using keycloak. Pod not initiating. shows following error

Tags: kubernetes

```
--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  labels: 
    app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: oauth2-proxy
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: oauth2-proxy
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - 
          args: 
            - provider= keycloak
            - set-xauthrequest= true
            - cookie-secret= xxxxxxxxx
            - provider-display-name= 'xxxx xxxx'
            - client-id= 'xxxx-xxxxx'
            - client-secret= 'xxxxxxxxxx'
            - login-url= 'xxxxxxxxx/auth/realms/xxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/auth'
            - redeem-url= 'xxxxxxx/auth/realms/xxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/token'
            - validate-url= 'xxxxxxxxx/auth/realms/xxxxxxx/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo'
            - keycloak-group= xxxxxxxx
          image: 'quay.io/oauth2-proxy/oauth2-proxy:latest'
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: oauth2-proxy
          ports: 
            - 
              containerPort: 4180
              protocol: TCP
        
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    app: oauth2-proxy
```

Oauth-proxy2 pod not initiating. Shows following error

ERROR :

> [2022/07/20 15:06:07] [main.go:54] invalid configuration:
> missing setting: cookie-secret
> provider missing setting: client-id
> missing setting: client-secret or client-secret-file
> missing setting for email validation: email-domain or authenticated-emails-file required.
> use email-domain=* to authorize all email addresses

Answer (score 1):

I think there is whitespace around the `=` sign in your args list for the container which is causing the problem. Try removing it, e-g change `- client-id= 'xxxx-xxxxx'` to `- client-id='xxxx-xxxxx'`. And same for all parameters.

Comment: solved it. it should be  **- -- provider= keycloak**  instead of **- provider= keycloak**. args should start with **- --** not with **-**. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, interesting :)

Comment: so why don't accept the answer?